# How to remove "Fruit" value from my text input area

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So i need to remove the value that i added at the text input area as a chip, but i dont know how to solve the codes to link the it together and remove it. So what should happen is when the proper codes are linked together, it should be able to be removed when i click the "x" on the chip.

i'm able to add the values, but when i click remove the values are still there.

```
          add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
            const input = event.input;
            const value = event.value;
            console.log(`mat chip`, event);
            console.log(`mat chip value`, value);

            // Add our fruit
            if ((value || '').trim()) {

              this.fruits.push({name: value.trim()});
              console.log(`fruits`, this.fruits);
              let type = this.editDeliveryOrderForm.value.type;
              type += ',' + value.trim();
              this.editDeliveryOrderForm.patchValue({
                type
              });
            }

            // Reset the input value
            if (input) {
              input.value = '';
            }
          }

          remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
            const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);
            const value = fruit.name;

            // console.log(`mat chip`, event);
            // console.log(`mat chip value`, value);

            if (index >= 0) {
              this.fruits.splice(index, 1);

              // this.fruits.push({name: value.trim()});
              // console.log(`fruits`, this.fruits);
              let type = this.editDeliveryOrderForm.value.type;
              value.trim();
              this.editDeliveryOrderForm.patchValue({
                type
              });
            }
```

Comment: can you add your code in stackbiz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsqwe5 i cant produce the output since im not that good in coding yet, but i produced the codes i have in stackblitz here.

Answer (score 0):

Array method **indexOf()** is case sensitive. The object which passed to fruits array does not return the index.

```
const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);
//console.log(index);

if(index !== -1) {
// code..
}
```

Comment: i dont understand, can u add it to my code above so i can see how?

Comment: Sure. I just checked your stackbiz. Following files are missing.  ../delivery-orders.service
./delivery-order-edit.component.html
./delivery-order-edit.component.scss

Comment: i think i confused you with my last stackblitz, try checking it out now. i hope u can connect the removing part cause thats what i need to solve right now please!

Comment: It gives can't find package app. :( Can you please fix all of the broken links. So that I can help you. BTW I'm unable to save in stackblitz. If not provide me fruits array and fruit object that called in remove() functions.

Comment: i dont know how to fix it, the whole project code is quite complicated. im not gonna be able to make it work at the stackblitz. My mentor says the part i need to fix starts at the "remove(fruit: Fruit): void {" area between "let type = this.editDeliveryOrderForm.value.type;" and "this.editDeliveryOrderForm.patchValue({
                    type
                  });"

im still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.filter() to filter the elements in array

```
remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
       this.fruits = this.fruits.filter((fr)=>fr.name !== fruit.name);
}
```

This will return new array removing the current fruit.

Comment: i dont get it maynnn i gottta change something between the let type = this.editDeliveryOrderForm.value.type; and this.editDeliveryOrderForm.patchValue({
                    type on the "remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
                const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);" area